# CSS Text Truncation Vertical Alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a lorem ipsum text that is truncated. When you press the "readmore »" button it fully displays the text.

My issue is the text shifts up vertically when you press the "readmore »" button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".readmore-btn").on("click",function(){
    $(".readmore").toggleClass("truncate");
  })
});
```

```css
.truncate {
  max-height: 55px;
  overflow-y:hidden;
}
.readmore-btn {
  color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Text before</h1>
<div class="readmore truncate">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus. Vestibulum congue nunc eget feugiat euismod. Praesent porta cursus libero, ut vestibulum leo suscipit non. Vivamus vulputate urna quis tincidunt congue. </p>
</div>
<div class="readmore-btn">Readmore »</div>
<h4>Text After</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the `overflow-y: hidden;` from the `.truncate` class and moving it to the `.readmore` class resolves the shifting issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".readmore-btn").on("click",function(){
    $(".readmore").toggleClass("truncate");
  })
});
```

```css
.readmore {
  overflow-y:hidden;
 }
.truncate {
  max-height: 55px;
  
}
.readmore-btn {
  color: #337ab7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>Text before</h1>
<div class="readmore truncate">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel lacus est. Ut vulputate venenatis mauris porta ornare. Nunc vehicula dapibus sem eget maximus. Vestibulum congue nunc eget feugiat euismod. Praesent porta cursus libero, ut vestibulum leo suscipit non. Vivamus vulputate urna quis tincidunt congue. Vestibulum malesuada neque sit amet eros efficitur pharetra. Vestibulum consequat purus sit amet ex euismod, ut consequat tellus vehicula. Proin suscipit in risus ut placerat. Integer porta id libero ac finibus. Ut at tellus turpis. Phasellus dolor erat, ullamcorper a risus ultrices, iaculis malesuada nisl. Integer tellus arcu, sodales quis mattis ac, sagittis eu turpis. Suspendisse tristique tempor pharetra.</p>
</div>
<div class="readmore-btn">Readmore »</div>
<h4>Text After</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the default margins the browsers adds to paragraphs.

Just add

```
.truncate p{margin:0}
```

to your css

Comment: Hey @alfredopacino -- while adding a margin of 0 resolves the bug displayed here -- if you remove the overflow-y: hidden entirely ( off of every single div ) the shifting no longer occurs. The unexpected interaction is a combination of overflow-y preventing margins from collapsing.